# Pegar nome de array dentro de array

Tags: array, lua

Bom, o que eu quero é o seguinte: pegar o nome de uma array dentro de outra array, apenas o nome.
EX:

```
local a = 
{
["oi"] = {sim=1, nao=2},
["tchau"] = {sim=2, nao=1}
}
local falas = {}
table.insert(falas, a)
```

-- Adicionaria os valores "oi" e "tchau" a tabela falas.
Essa é a intenção, mas não sei como faz.

Comment: Já tentou usar uma matriz?

Answer (score 5):

Seria isso que você quer?

```
local n = 0
for k,v in pairs(a) do
    n = n+1
    falas[n] = k
end
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/4zPfF1). Fonte: [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12674345/520779).

Comment: arrays em Lua começam de 1, ao invés de começar em zero. (vc pode usar table.insert se nao quiser se preocupar c isso)

Comment: ah, esquece o que eu falei. O n=n+1 no início do loop é meio esquisito mas tá certo (nunca duvide do lhf, hahaha)

Comment: Obrigado, fiz:
for a, b in pairs(a) do
table.insert(falas, a)
end

Mas não ficou na ordem que estava na outra tabela, tem como fazer ficar?

Comment: @GabrielSales Segundo a pergunta linkada, não, pois as chaves não têm ordem definida. Você pode até ordenar as chaves, mas **preservar a ordem** na qual elas apareceram no código-fonte, receio que não é possível. Entretanto, sou iniciante em Lua, então pode ter algo que eu não sei a respeito. (P.S. Achei [isto](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OrderedTable), será que ajuda em alguma coisa?)